# Compiling application in release

Tags: android, android-ndk

Im using Eclipse with ADT plugin and Sequoia, and Im trying to deploy my app in "release" mode but even if I change my Application.mk and Android.mk file with -03 I keep seeing -O2 -DNDEBUG -g plugged in the console... Where can I unset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That **is** release mode.

If you want to change the default debug/release behavior, take a look at /ndk/build/core/add-application.mk and search for "APP_OPTIM"